# Scaffold role management for Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Is there an easy way to quickly scaffold the screens and controller code (using UserManager and RollManager) for Identity 2.0?

Al the examples I've seen involve hand-cranking it. It would be nice to easily generate the screens etc to at least add new roles and then add ApplicationUsers to those roles.

Thanks

Comment: Guess there isn't anything. I ended up using this excellent tutorial though: http://openlightgroup.com/Blog/TabId/58/PostId/189/UserRolesAdministration.aspx (thanks to the author)